# GNOME extension "Internet Radio" not working while session locked

Tags: lock-screen, gnome-shell-extension, internet-radio

I am using the GNOME extension "Internet Radio" under Ubuntu 17.10. It works perfectly fine, except that it is automatically switched off every time the session is locked.

I would like it to continue working even while the session is locked. I tried googling several of these keywords, but it returned nothing, so I do not even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is as per GNOME's security policy, whenever you enter the lock screen *all* the extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in, and then the extensions get re-enabled.

So the only feasible workaround is to keep the screen unlocked all the time. You may use an extension like [Keep awake!](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1097/keep-awake/) to prevent automatic screen-locking.

Comment: OK, I see. Any recommended way to momentarily disable accidental keyboard/mouse inputs (e.g. from toddlers or animals) while keeping the session unlocked?

Comment: @EmmanuelMarcq Sadly, I'm not aware of any such feature. You may try asking a new question providing link to this question for context.